# 'mutable' in type definition

Tags: f#

Why is disabled types like

```
type t = A of int | B of string * mutable int
```

while such types are allowed:

```
type t = A of int | B of string * int ref
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question is, how would you modify the value of a mutable element of discriminated union case? For `ref` types, this is quite easy, because `ref` is a reference cell (a record actually) which contains the mutable value:

```
match tval with
| B(str, refNum) -> refNum := 4
```

We extract the reference cell and assign it to a new symbol (or a new variable) `refNum`. Then we modify the value inside the ref cell, which also modifies `tval`, because the two references to the cell (from discriminated union case and from `refNum` variable) are aliased.

On the other hand, when you write `let mutable n = 0`, you're creating a variable, which can be directly mutated, but there is no cell holding the mutable value - the variable `n` is directly mutable. This shows the difference:

```
let mutable a = 10
let mutable b = a
b <- 5   // a = 10, b = 5

let a = ref 10
let b = a
b := 5   // a = 5, b = 5 (because of aliasing!)
```

So, to answer your question - there is no way to directly refer to the value stored inside the discriminated union case. You can only extract it using pattern matching, but that copies the value to a new variable. This means that there isn't any way you could modify the `mutable` value.

**EDIT**
To demonstrate limitations of `mutable` values in F#, here is one more example - you cannot capture `mutable` values inside a closure:

```
let foo() = 
  let mutable n = 0
  (fun () -> n <- n + 1; n) // error FS0407
```

I think the reason is same as with discriminated union cases (even though it's not as obvious in this case). The compiler needs to copy the variable - it is stored as a local variable and as a field in the generated closure. And when copying, you want to modify the same variable from multiple references, so *aliasing semantics* is the only reasonable thing to do...

Comment: By creating variable typed as discriminated union as record we already holding some memory cells, isn't it?
I suppose, by using pattern matching we create yet another binding to existing memory cell, nor creating new direcly mutable variable, isn't?
On other side, your arguments seems reasonable, but Leroy while described ZINC shows such syntax is possible.

Comment: I checked ZINC and it really uses `mutable` inside discriminated unions. Though it's not clear to me whether it follows the _aliasing semantics_ or whether you can change the value only via the symbol bound in pattern matching (if that's the case, it seems a bit inconsistent to me - because pattern matching already copied the value from union case to a symbol...)

Comment: As far as i understend ZINC's code Leroy just bind an name used into pattern matching to the label of DU or record's member (and the label is just index into table of offsets to DU member).
So, in case F# compiler creates local copy of DU member it's really impossible. Thank you very much!

Comment: Tomas, Hi! I do really apologize, but could you check the case with closure in the latest version of F# or FSI. I did really write a program, which mutated a variable inside a closure. Then, as far as I can remember it was even mutated in the parent scope. I guess F# uses the same preprocessor trick as C# does moving enclosed symbols from stack to heap - you could google for "What's in closures" (I don't actually remember, cuz I'm on work now and don't even have VS2008/10 here. Eclipse only :))

Comment: @Tomas: Here's the link I wrote about: <http://diditwith.net/2007/02/09/WhatsInAClosure.aspx>

Comment: @Bubba88: No, F# doesn't use the same trick as C#. It simply captures reference to an object (which is why you need to use `ref`, which creates an object instead of `mutable` which simply marks local value as mutable).

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, you were right. I just was mistaken, cuz I was playing in FSI where the scope is aka global, so my functions were not as closures. I've just checked the case with regular local scope and closures, and everything just failed as you told. Thx for pointing to that. It's not so much good though, cause full-fledged closures could be of more help than pure OCaml-ported version :)

Comment: @Bubba88: That's a tricky issue - full closures in C# are often very confusing (e.g. the well-known issue with capturing variable in a `for` loop). Since F# prefers immutable code, it makes some sense to avoid capturing mutable state.

Answer (score 5):

Ref is a type (`int ref = ref<int>`). Mutable is not a type, it's a keyword that allows you to update a value.

Example:

```
let (bla:ref<int>) = ref 0 //yup
let (bla:mutable<int>) = 3 //no!
```

Comment: Your example just shows there isn't such type as mutable. Yes, i agree: mutable is just mark to compiler to use some syntax sugar. I can imagine why that mark not allowed to be included to environment and so we can't use mutable variables with closures.

IMHO, by creating variable typed as discriminated union as record we already eat some memory cells (f.e. ref is no more then {mutable 'a val}).

So why discriminated union can't hold mutable?